# Alternate ways of applying method to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, scope

I am working on pre-course material for a coding boot camp. So, I'm looking for guidance, not the answer. I'm at a loss for how to approach this question. There is an HTML file that checks each step of the answer. With the code, I've currently written (below), I keep getting this response --"expected {} to have a property 'push'" and the same error for 'pop'. I believe I am adding the methods incorrectly. But I couldn't find any other way to add a method besides using prototype, which applies the method to all Array objects. I also tried doing simple tests which also failed.

```
// returns an empty array object. this object should have the following    methods:
// push(val) adds val to the end of the array
// pop() removes a value from the end and returns it
// the goal of this problem is to reverse engineer what array methods are actually doing and return an object that has those methods
function createArray() {
    //CODE HERE
    var array = [];
    array.push = function(val){ 
        array[array.length] = val;
        return array;   
    };
    array.pop = function(){
        return array[array.length-1];
    };

}
createArray();
console.log(array.push(hey));
```

And the error message:

```
console.log(array.push(hey));
            ^
ReferenceError: array is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Fox/Documents/Programming/Codesmith/precourse-part-1/Level-2-Intermediate/src/main.js:67:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I realize array is a local variable. But once I call the function createArray shouldn't it be global? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I'm new to coding. Please, be gentle.

Comment: Your variable `array` is local to the function `createArray` – so you can not access it outside of the function in your `console.log` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the array inside the function so it is function scoped. It will not be accessible from outside that function. What you can do is return the array from the function and assign the result to a variable.

```
 function createArray() {
    var array = [];
    array.push = function(val){ 
        array[array.length] = val;
        return array;   
    };
    array.pop = function(){
        return array[array.length-1];
    };

    return array;
}

var myArray = createArray();
console.log(myArray.push('hey')); // ["hey"]
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lo5Laon/**